# CSRF on YAJRA datatable Laravel5.5 not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, yajra-datatable

I have this code where I needed to store in a variable so I display it in view,
I've tried different approach of packing the "Form header" and using CSRF is not working

```
$return = '<form method="post" action="/procurement/add-product">
    '.{{ csrf_token() }}.'
    <input type="hidden" name= "product_id" value=".$row->id.">
    <input type="text" name="product_qty"  class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Item</button>
    </form>';

    return $return;
```

Here is my route

```
Route::post('/procurement/add-product','ProductController@addProcurementProduct');
```

Here is the JAvascript part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#procurement-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ url('procurement/get_procurement_datatable') }}',
        columns : [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'po_number', name: 'po_number'},
            {data: 'action', searchable: false, orderable: false},
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
            {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'}
        ]
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: What your route for update?

Comment: I'm using a resource route Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');

Comment: I already added my route

Comment: Why you changed the question?, First you asking about '<form>' now working proper with update action and now you changed your question completely. It should be your another question don't play like game here please....

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvLtd I already created a new question since you suggest to create a new one. btw im not playing here.

Comment: Hello, would you mind to provide your frontend part? The javascript could be specially helpful

Comment: @Asur hi already added sa JS part

Answer (score 0):

I've added missing hidden field `csrf_token()` which is require while submit and authorize form submission at laravel.

```
$return = '<form method="post" action="{{ action('ProcurementController@update', $details->id) }}">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><!--Added csrf missing field-->
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
    <input type="text" name="product_qty"  class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Item</button>
    </form>';
```

Comment: @MartneyAcha: np, let me know which error/exception you facing?

Comment: I already manage to fix it by adding the URI restriction to VerifyCsrfToken.php , thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your action like this :

```php
<form method="PUT" action="{{ route('product.update', $details->id) }}">
```

Check this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Maybe you will have to add the csrf_token to your form.

or you can do with Blade Form https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html :

```php
{!! Form::open(array('url' => route('product.update', $details->id), 'method' => 'PUT') !!}
<input>
<input>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

edit : You have to use PUT/PATCH method to your form (see the link about resource controllers)

Comment: @MartneyAcha Ok, but have you tried my action form ? Does it work ?

Comment: Yes, but Im not sure if this is the right answer cause its still not working.

Comment: @MartneyAcha you have to use PUT/PATCH method I edited my response, you can see the doc => https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Return the form to another blade like view/products/datatables.blade.php

Example: The controller should looks like:-

```
public function getproducts()
{
$product = Product::all(); //Product is Model name

return Datatables::of($product)
    ->addColumn('action', function($product)
    {
          return view('product.datatables', compact('product'))->render();
    })->make(true);

}
```

And the view should look as below:

```
<a href="{{ route('product.edit', ['$id' => $product->id]) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
<form action="/product/{{ $product->id }}" method="post" id="deleteForm">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

It will work just fine. Because the mustache {{}} can't be read in the controller. We redirect the things to the blade

Answer (score 0):

you can use [datatables draw function](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) , no need to remove `csrf` protection

Example: at your laravel blade `head`

```
<head>
...
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
...
</head>
```

at javascript :

```
// get CSRF Token from head
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');    

// Your Datatable
var table = $('#procurement-table').DataTable();

// just add this after you declare your datatables 
// this will run every datatable redraw the table content
table.on( 'draw', function () {
    // console.log( 'Redraw occurred at: '+new Date().getTime() );
    // filling csrf token every getmecsrf class
    $(".getmecsrf").val(CSRF_TOKEN);
} );
```

at your laravel `Controller` or per your return logic, you should add class at  csrf, 
in my case i use `.getmecsrf`

```
$return = '<form ...>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" class="getmecsrf" value="" />
...
</form>';

return $return;
```