# CSRF on Yajra Datatable Laravel not working

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I have this code in laravel and used YAJRA as my datatable and upon submitting it says that the CSRF token is error, attached here is my code in Controller before rending in View/Blade.
Here is my code:

```
 $return = '<form method="post" action="/procurement/add-product">
            '.{{ csrf_token() }}.'
            <input type="hidden" name= "product_id" value=".$row->id.">
            <input type="text" name="product_qty"  class="form-control">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Item</button>
            </form>';

            return $return;
```

Comment: why do you have  {{csrf_token()}} wrapped in '. ?

Comment: So I can render it in view, This code is from my controller.

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833707/4939915) for how to add csrf field into form

Comment: You can also add the route to the `exceptions`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSRF on YAJRA datatable Laravel5.5 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833401/csrf-on-yajra-datatable-laravel5-5-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer via documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf
I just put the URI of the said form

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
        'procurement/*',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the form to another blade like view/products/datatables.blade.php

Example: The controller should looks like:-

```
public function getproducts()
{
    $product = Product::all(); //Product is Model name

    return Datatables::of($product)
        ->addColumn('action', function($product)
        {
              return view('product.datatables', compact('product'))->render();
        })->make(true);

}
```

And the view should look as below:

```
<a href="{{ route('product.edit', ['$id' => $product->id]) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
<form action="/product/{{ $product->id }}" method="post" id="deleteForm">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

It will work just fine. Because the mustache {{}} can't be read in the controller. We redirect the things to the blade