# How to use csrf token in Laravel Yajra datables and '.{{ csrf_token() }}.' not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code in laravel and used YAJRA datatables and can't use csrf token. Here is my code:

```
return DataTables::of($destroyList)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($destroyList){

                return '<form id="delete-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
                           <a href="#" data-id="'. $destroyList->id .'" title="Restore?" class="restore"> <i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i></a>
                          &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
                          <a href="#" data-id="'. $destroyList->id .'" title="Parmanent Delete?" class="ptrash"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </a>
                          </form>';
            })
            ->toJson();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSRF on YAJRA datatable Laravel5.5 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833401/csrf-on-yajra-datatable-laravel5-5-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a PHP function, you can't use `blade` syntax, but you also don't have to. Simply remove `{{ csrf_field() }}` and replace it with the PHP equivalent:

```
return '<form id="delete-data">'.csrf_field().'<a href="#" data-id="'. $destroyList->id .'" title="Restore?" class="restore"> <i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" data-id="'. $destroyList->id .'" title="Parmanent Delete?" class="ptrash"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></form>';
```

`csrf_field()` as a global function that returns the HTML necessary for hidden input field, so using it in this string will output

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="...">
```

Into your string.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add a complex view to a dataTable column, you could use a custom blade view for that.

```
->addColumn('action', function ($destroyList){
   return view('destroyList.action'['destroyList' =>$destroyList]);
});
```

Then create a file `action.blade.php` in your `resources/views/destroyList` folder with your required html:

```
<form id="delete-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
    <a href="#" data-id="{{ $destroyList->id }}" title="Restore?" class="restore"> <i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i></a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
    <a href="#" data-id="{{ $destroyList->id }}" title="Parmanent Delete?" class="ptrash"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your laravel version higher of 5.5 then not working.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

> @csrf
>
> {{ csrf_field() }}

And laravel version 5.6 & Version ++
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf

> @csrf

CSRF Token as well as use between the form tag